# Django/ HTML image is breaking and size of image is not ok

Tags: html, django

[image: issue]

hi all,

I am developing locally Django site, seems I have two issues here:

1. One picture on top is like 4 times smaller that original picture, original is size  610x 150px.
   I would like to have my picture on page same size as original, how I can do it?
2. Picture below" About us" seems has no gap on right side, on left side you can see gap between picture and square. Also this is working fine on full screen but when I make page smaller above mentioned happens. Do you know reason?

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Django Central</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"> 
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: "Tangerine", serif;
            font-size: 37;
            background-color: #fdfdfd;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .btn-danger {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00000;
            border-color: #dc281e;
        }
        .masthead {
            background: #3398E1;
            height: auto;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            width: 610px;
            height: 150px;
            object-fit: contain; 
    </style>
        {% load static %}
               <center> <img src="{% static 'blog/moj.png' %}" alt="My image"> </center>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Django central</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Content Goes here -->
        {% endblock content %}
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="py-3 bg-grey">
            <p class="m-0 text-dark text-center ">Copyright &copy; Django Central</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }
    
    .head_text {
        color: black;
    }
    
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
    }
</style>

<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h3 class=" site-heading my-4 mt-3 text-black"> Welcome to my awesome Blog </h3>
                    <p class="text-light">We Love Django As much as you do..! &nbsp
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

sidebar.html:

```
{% block sidebar %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
       img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            object-fit: contain;        
</style>

<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
<div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">About Us</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% load static %}
        <center><img src="{% static 'blog/zdjecie.png' %}" alt="My image"></center>
        <p class="card-text"> This awesome blog is made on the top of our Favourite full stack Framework 'Django', follow up the tutorial to learn how we made it..!</p>
        <a href="https://djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django"
           class="btn btn-danger">Know more!</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Comment: Try to specify image size with classes not with tag on your css

Comment: Your problem is the css, it's not good idea to specify images sizes in px, use with: 100% and height: auto

Comment: Luis seems after updating as you mentioned, all is ok. Thanks !